# Setting predefined values for a column in database

Tags: database

I am creating a table

```
create tabel xyz
( id number (10) not null,
  code char(1) ,

primary key (id)
)
```

I want the user to have predefined values for code column like P, S, C.
How to do that?
Currently I am using code char(1) DEFAULT('P','S','C')
but with this I am getting error. 
Please suggest and also I want this column to be not null...

Answer (score 1):

`ENUM` column type is easy but can come back to haunt you. I would recommend adding a 'lookup' table which will house the values you speak of, then adding a 'value_id' column to your primary object table, something like:

```
primary_table:
    id
    value_id

value_table:
    id:
    name: #P, S, C
```

If your table is large and you need to change any of the enum values, you will have to run an alter on the table which could mean significant downtime.

Comment: @RafaelBarros: Ya, I add unique keys to all my lookup tables.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on mysql, use enum:

```
code ENUM('P', 'S', 'C')
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

Comment: thank you everyone for the suggestions. I'll use one of the solution based on my application.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display those values to the user, it's probably easiest to create another table, and use a foreign key reference.  You *could* implement this as a CHECK constraint in a dbms that enforces CHECK constraints, but presenting the valid choices to the user would be troublesome.

```
-- You'll want to restrict permissions on this table pretty tightly. Very few
-- people should be allowed to change it.
create table xyz_codes (
  code char(1) primary key CHECK (code in ('P', 'S', 'C'))
);

insert into xyz_codes values ('P'), ('S'), ('C');

create table xyz ( 
  id integer primary key,
  code char(1) references xyz_codes (code)
);
```

Having done that, the following INSERT statement will fail with a foreign key violation.

```
insert into xyz values (1, 'D');
```

But this one will succeed.

```
insert into xyz values (1, 'C');
```

To select valid choices for presentation to the user, use

```
select code 
from xyz_codes
order by code;
```